# canvas ball deflect from ball drawn with arc

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video, html5-canvas

I have two balls (circles) which are flying around in my HTML. If they come together, they should deflect and fly to the other direction back. I have drawn the circles with arc and I have variables for the x,y koordinates and the radius.

```
var xGreen;
var yGreen;
var rGreen;
var xOrange;
var yOrange;
var rOrange;
```

Because they should move, I just change the x and y Position:

```
xGreen += xSpeed;
yGreen += ySpeed;
xOrange += xSpeed;
yOrange += ySpeed;
```

So how can I find out when the circles are colliding?

Comment: you can use the distance formula based on the center of each circle and their radii: `distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xG-xO,2)+Math.pow(yG-yO,2))`. Then you can tell if they collide by checking if that distance is less than the sum of the radii of each ball.

Comment: wow thanks, that works perfekt! I did not know about Math.sqrt! How can i mark a comment as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xG-xO,2)+Math.pow(yG-yO,2))`

Then you can tell if they collide by checking if that distance is less than the sum of the radii of each ball.